# Is this endgame winnable for either side?

Tags: analysis, endgame, winning

I'm a complete novice in chess and I don't know if this even qualifies as endgame with so many pieces left, but I ended up in this position playing as black vs. a king's pawn debut. I sort of tried to play king's gambit of my own, despite playing black. As you can see, I won on timer, but is this position winnable to either side, or it a stalemate / draw? Assuming both sides play perfectly, of course - which they did not up to this point, but my question is theoretical.

```
[Title "White to move: Is it draw?"]
[FEN "2k3r1/1p3p2/2p5/p2r3p/8/P2P3P/1P2RK1P/6R1 w - - 0 1"]
[Startflipped "1"]
```

The only advantage for black that I can see is the pawns being advanced one more line, my goal would be to sneak one pawn up to the 1 line, but it's hard to see for me whether that's doable.

Comment: Whose turn?  It looks like whoever moves first wins a Rook.  It seems like it's White's turn since Black has just played R(x)d5, so 1 Rxg8+ wins.  If it were Black's turn then 1 . . . Rf5+ would for 2 Ke3(Ke1) and then Rxg1(+) would win.  If Black's move was not a capture then Black could have won with either Rf5+ or Rxe2+.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: white to move. Thanks for the analysis! Indeed, I missed that obvious move, looks like the best black can do is trade two rooks for one, and white will have a hard time losing. Funny how the timer changes everything in clocked games.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With white to move, as you indicated, it is a trivial win for white. Your rook on g8 is en prise to the white rook on g1. White plays RxR+ and you are just a rook down.

Comment: The irony is last move black had Rxe2+ Kxe2 Rxg1 winning a rook themselves. Hilarious post OP, thanks for the chuckle.